# .NET Application Pool Crash NLSSorting.dll access violation exception (0xC0000005)

Tags: asp.net, .net, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET website running in .NET 4.5. Since it went live several months ago we started receiving occasional and randomly timed crashes. In most case the website will slow do for a while and then recover to normal speed, in more severe cases the application pool crashes.

The event viewer offers little in the way of assistance, so I installed some additional debug software.

Making sense of the crash dump is difficult, there does not appear to be any indication of which page or function in my code was causing the error, just some references to .net functions.

One thing I have read is that this error is most likely caused by a recursive loop somewhere in the code... the crash dump repeated the following lines about 40 times so in theory this could be the recursive function but how can I find out more on it?

```
System_Web_ni+2163b0     015136a8     02b4fa04     0a7b94b0     0f588300    
System_Web_ni+2163fc     00000014     00000000     00000005     0f588220    
System_Web_ni+21e397     00000001     02b4ff1c     00000001     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21df85     00000001     067ed14c     02992900     06933770    
System_Web_ni+21deb9     02b4ff1c     0f588398     6ba7de4b     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21de67     00000000     02b50344     0f588428     0f5883a8    
System_Web_ni+21de4b     02b50344     00000000     00000000     00000000    
System_Web_ni+81e6cc     00000000     00000000     029629e0     02b4fa04    
System_Web_ni+81dfa3     00000001     00000000     02991590     0f588720    
System_Web_ni+81e83a     00000001     00000000     02b47a34     0112e6ed    
System_Web_ni+81e875     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
0x0112de53     068e3f5c     02b47dc0     02b47a34     0f588aa4
```

Here is the DebugDiag log... minus a few duplications of the above (it exceeds SO limits with it all).

```
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   22/08/2016 10:09:42 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.78 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.15 

.NET Call Stack

Function 
System.Globalization.CompareInfo.InternalGetGlobalizedHashCode(IntPtr, IntPtr, System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Int64) 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 


Full Call Stack



Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
nlssorting+34fc     02125760     00000001     029d07d8     0000000e    
clr!SortVersioning::SortDllGetSortKey+33     029d07d8     0000000e     00000000     00000000    
clr!COMNlsInfo::InternalGetGlobalizedHashCode+184     02125760     6feee7c3     027b1230     029d07d8    
mscorlib_ni+3b9803     00000000     00000000     00000000     08000001    
mscorlib_ni+3a403f     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000001    
mscorlib_ni+3a3fed     6d642750     0f5620a0     6d5a550e     0f5620b0    
mscorlib_ni+3a277d     0f5620b0     6d5a54bf     028ca2d8     029d07d0    
mscorlib_ni+30550e     028ca2d8     029d07d0     0f5620f8     6d5a53ba    
mscorlib_ni+3054bf     0f5620e4     0f5620e8     00000059     0f5620dc    
mscorlib_ni+3053ba     0f562108     6ed3733a     0f562110     6eda3099    
System_ni+187594     0f562110     6eda3099     0f56213c     0112f68c    
System_ni+18733a     0f56213c     0112f68c     00000000     028ca288    
System_ni+1f3099     00000000     028ca288     00000000     029d07d0    
0x0112f68c     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
0x0112f454     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
0x0112e62e     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
0x0112de53     068e3f5c     02de0f70     02de0be4     0f562764    


(The below is repeated about 40 times)

System_Web_ni+2163b0     015136a8     02de06cc     0a7b94b0     0f562764    
System_Web_ni+2163fc     00000014     00000000     00000005     0f562684    
System_Web_ni+21e397     00000001     02de0be4     00000001     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21df85     00000001     067ed14c     02992900     06933770    
System_Web_ni+21deb9     02de0be4     0f5627fc     6ba7de4b     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21de67     00000000     02de100c     0f56288c     0f56280c    
System_Web_ni+21de4b     02de100c     00000000     00000000     00000000    
System_Web_ni+81e6cc     00000000     00000000     029629e0     02de06cc    
System_Web_ni+81dfa3     00000001     00000000     02991590     0f562b84    
System_Web_ni+81e83a     00000001     00000000     02dd86fc     0112e6ed    
System_Web_ni+81e875     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
0x0112de53     068e3f5c     02dd8a88     02dd86fc     0f562f08    

(The above is repeated about 40 times)

System_Web_ni+2163b0     6b9bcb70     0298f5dc     0a7b94b0     0f59ea1c    
System_Web_ni+2163fc     00020c5b     0f59e8a8     00000000     ffffffff    
System_Web_ni+21e397     00000001     0298f5dc     00000001     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21df85     00000001     067ed14c     02992900     06933770    
System_Web_ni+21deb9     0298f5dc     0f59eab4     6ba7de4b     00000000    
System_Web_ni+21de67     00000000     069323a4     06938c5c     0f59eac4    
System_Web_ni+21de4b     06938c5c     0f59ea38     0f59edc0     6fff46c0    
System_Web_ni+220f9d     0000000f     70de90ae     02940d3c     00000000    
System_Web_ni+1ce516     0f59ebf4     00000000     00000000     0693a838    
System_Web_ni+1dc6e3     00000000     00000000     0f59ec84     0f59ec90    
System_Web_ni+1cee80     06821c74     0f59ec78     0f59ed28     a8a84fa1    
System_Web_ni+1db222     069323a4     a8a84fa1     6faba404     0f59f25c    
System_Web_ni+1cfce0     00000000     0000000b     00000002     00000000    
System_Web_ni+1cf9cf     00c511cc     01447a7c     0000000b     00000000    
webengine4!MgdGetServerVariableW+269     01447a7c     00000000     01446d80     01446d80    
webengine4!MgdGetNextNotification+136     00000080     00000000     021d3524     01446dd8    
webengine4!MgdGetServerVariableW+210     00000080     00000000     021d3524     01446d80    
webengine4!MgdWebSocketWriteFragment+a83     01446d80     01446dd8     01446d84     0f59ef10    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+128     021d3524     01446d80     00000000     01446dd8    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+305     00000000     00000000     00000000     01446d80    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+28     00000000     00000000     00000000     01446d80    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoStateRequestExecuteHandler+36     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoWork+d7     00000000     00000000     00000001     01446d80    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ContinueNotificationLoop+1f     00000000     00000000     0f59f340     0f59f228    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ProcessIndicateCompletion+1f     00000000     01447a7c     0f59f238     7150ef12    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::IndicateCompletion+75     00000000     71510a52     0f59f248     71510a74    
webengine4!STRU::Unescape+423     00000000     021c65a8     0f59f288     6ba85bad    
webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+22     01447a7c     0f59f340     a8a84fa1     6faba404    
System_Web_ni+225bad     a8a84fa1     6faba404     0f59f45c     6b88fd90    
System_Web_ni+1cfe83     00000004     00000003     9de68411     00000000    
System_Web_ni+1cf9cf     021c65a8     0f59f41c     6fbb85f3     0f59f574    
clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+10     0f59f574     00000010     009fd9ac     0f061c80    
clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+76     0f59f508     9de68329     0f061c96     00000002    
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+b3     00000002     6fbb8582     0f59f508     01000001    
clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+92     ffffffff     009fd9ac     0f59f574     00000010    
0x009fda27     00000000     01447a7c     00000003     00000004    
webengine4!MgdGetServerVariableW+269     700fd668     714b94f2     0f59f5e8     6fb89c65    
webengine4!MgdGetServerVariableW+2c3     01447a7c     9de68279     0f59f615     0f59f617    
clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+1ce     0f59f615     0f59f617     00010002     021c65a8    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+42     9de681c1     6fb8b4d2     00000000     021c4590    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+390     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4d     021c4590     0f59f8cc     770b9902     021c4590    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e     021c4590     4256efbf     00000000     00000000    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70     6fbb6088     021c4590     ffffffff     77147514    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b     6fbb6088     021c4590     00000000     00000000    

Exception Information
NLSSORTING+34FCWARNING - DebugDiag was not able to locate debug symbols for nlssorting.dll, so the information below may be incomplete.

In W3F35D~1.DMP the assembly instruction at nlssorting+34fc in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x0f560ce8 on thread 26

Module Information 
Image Name: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll   Symbol Type:  Export 
Base address: 0x00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Fri Nov 06 02:20:51 2015  
Checksum: 0x00000000   Comments:  Flavor=Retail 
COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  Microsoft Collation Support 
ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2 
Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  nlssorting.dll 
VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
Loaded Image Name:  nlssorting.dll   Legal Trademarks:   
Mapped Image Name:     Original filename:  nlssorting.dll 
Module name:  nlssorting   Private Build:  DDBLD400 
Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  Microsoft® .NET Framework 
Module Size:  76.00 KBytes   Product Version:  4.6.1055.0 
Symbol File Name:  nlssorting.dll   Special Build:  &
```

Any help or advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you running .NET Framework 4.6.0?

Comment: Yes I am - is this a bug with it?

Comment: 4.6.01055 to be precise. However the problem occurred in .net 4.5 also.